# Query builder - left join not working correctly

Tags: laravel

I have two tables: posts and category. Some posts have assigned category, others not. I want to display posts with category names (it's not important they are joinde or not). I'm using leftJoin()

```
$fposts=DB::table('posts')->leftJoin('category', 'category.id', '=','posts.category_id')->get();
return response()->view('main',['fposts'=>$fposts]);enter code here
```

As result I receive only posts with assigned categories. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: The query looks fine and should return all posts regardless of them having an assigned category.  Have you looked at your data to verify that you have posts without assigned categories?  Is this the entire query?  The reason I ask is because if you have a where on there that's looking at the category table, it can effectively turn your left join into an inner join.

Comment: Yes I have posts with category_id=NULL

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly on the db server and verifying results?  I'm fairly convinced the query is not your problem here.

Comment: Everything is working. It was my fault. I was observing wrong table. I added select() method to the query and now everything looks fine. I'm sorry for confusion.